# Angular 2 dynamic template

Tags: angular

I have a navbar with a dynamic route and i also want to use 1 template. So if i do a request to http://domain/com/aaa i am gettin gthe data from an array.

How can i achieve that?

**navbar.component.html**:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items"><a [routerLink]="[item.slug]" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">{{item.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

**navbar.componetns.ts**:

```
items = [
  { id:"1" , slug: "aaa" , name: "AAA"},
  { id:"2" , slug: "bbb" , name: "BBB"},
  { id:"3" , slug: "ccc" , name: "CCC"},
  { id:"4" , slug: "ddd" , name: "DDD"}
];
```

**app.routing.ts**:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '' , component: HomeComponent}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**item.service**:

```
export class ItemService {
  getItems() {
    return [
      { id:"1" , slug: "aaa" , name: "AAA"},
      { id:"2" , slug: "bbb" , name: "BBB"},
      { id:"3" , slug: "ccc" , name: "CCC"},
      { id:"4" , slug: "ddd" , name: "DDD"}
    ];
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem ? error  ?

Comment: @Pardeep Jain , i want to add a template, if i click on on AAA i want the data to display that belongs to AAA, so with an array.

Comment: I understand, but what i want is when the request is dom.com/aaa or dom.com/bbb it displays the data to 1 component and not to AaaComponent and BbbComponent, so a dynamic component?! Also an item-detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set params in the root component, cause the root is not an angular component. See this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-151326461

> The reason why this is not working is that your index.html in which
>   you place the  is not an angular
>   component. Because of this, Angular won't compile this element. And
>   Angular does not read attribute values during runtime, only during
>   compile time, as otherwise we would get a performance hit.

So you need a one level common component, and add the slug as a param into the router.

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '' , component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/common:slug' , component: CommonComponent}
];
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that

Comment: But how can i achieve domain.com/:slug ?!

Comment: yo can not do that. you only have params in a second level, as domain.com/component/:slug. Same component for all

Comment: I am new at angular sorry, so i have to create for each "slug" AAA, BBB CCC a component, like AaaComponent, etc etc but the displayed content structure is the same (id , name and description) and need one template and 1 component.

Comment: No, you need to create only one component, which receives a param :slug,